# ¿En la arquitectura mvc mi controlador se puede conectar con distintos modelos?

Tags: mvc, diseño

por ejemplo: Si deseo registrar un vehiculo(atributos: modelo, placa , año) y este tiene una marca( atributos: nombre, pais)

Mi clase controladorVehiculo solo se puede conectar con mi clase modeloVehiculo y modeloVehiculo se conectaria con modeloMarca
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o mi clase controladorVehiculo se conectaria con mi clase modeloMarca y mi clase modeloVehiculo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy realizando un proyecto y realmente tengo muchas dudas en como trabaja el patron de arquitectura mvc en estas situaciones

Comment: ¿Que lenguaje usa? Con .Net si se puede hacer.

Comment: en realidad es independiente del lenguaje, el trabajo es sobre patrón de arquitectura,mi duda es sobre como trabaja en esos casos el patrón mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrían existir diferentes posibilidades dependiendo del caso concreto y del lenguaje y la plataforma utilizados. Pero, en general, cuando los modelos (tipos, clases, ...) definidos en una aplicación no se ajustan a las necesidades de la información a mostrar en una vista lo que se suele hacer es definir un modelo específico para trabajar con la vista, lo que se denomina "modelo de vista".

Ten en cuenta que el patrón MVC es un patrón específico para trabajar en la capa de presentación de la aplicación. Los modelos utilizados en la capa de presentación no tienen porqué coincidir exactamente con los modelos utilizados en la capa de negocio, de hecho lo normal es que no coincidan salvo en aplicaciones muy simples.

En tu caso podrías crear un modelo InfoVehiculo y el controlador sería el responsable de obtener la información de los diferentes modelos de la capa de negocio (modeloVehiculo, modeloMarca, ....) y montar con ella el modelo InfoVehiculo que sería el que pasara a la vista.

Igualmente sería el responsable de recibir de la vista el modelo InfoVehiculo y pasar a la capa de negocio de la aplicación la información recibida en los modelos definidos en esta capa (modeloVehiculo, modeloMarca, ...).